# How to add two activity in android studio using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I have made an app. When i try to go to another activity, the app crashes. But the home page works perfectly. I have checked but i haven't found any problem. I have checked all the files, they are all good. Please solve this problem or tell me the process of adding two activities.